# Change div image AND text on hover with one link

Tags: html, css, rollover

I have a DIV that needs to change the opacity of an image on rollover AND the color of the text. At the moment rolling over the image triggers the image opacity but has no effect on the text and vice versa.

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="promo-box">
        <div class="promo-box-image">
        <img src="img.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="promo-box-content">
        Text Content
        </div>
     </div>                       
</a>

.promo-box-image {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.promo-box-image:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.promo-box-content {
    color: #fff;
}
.promo-box-content:hover {
    color: #ffcc00;
}
```

Any idea to make both events happen via rolling over ANY part of the outside DIV/href?

Comment: You need to set the `:hover` or `:focus` event on `#promo-box` instead.

Comment: not sure i understand how that allows me to keep both events happening?

Comment: For example: `#promo-box:hover .promo-box-image { opacity: 1} `

Comment: perfect! thanks. make it an answer and you get the win.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the hover states on the anchor itself, then base the selectors afterwards.

For example:

```
a:hover .promo-box-image {
    opacity: 1;
}

a:hover .promo-box-content {
    color: #ffcc00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

meh, just do it with jquery

```
$("#promo-box").hover(
  function() {
    $('.promo-box-image').css('opacity',0.7);
    $('.promo-box-content').css('color','red');
  }, function() {
$('.promo-box-image').css('opacity',1);
   $('.promo-box-content').css('color','black');
  }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/jLn252vy/

Or do it on the box itself:

```
#promo-box:hover {
  opacity:0.7;
  color:red;
}

#promo-box {

    width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/tkefLx42/